# ReactiveSearch query and results behavior

Tags: autocomplete, reactivesearch

I'm trying to get my search app to work with ReactiveSearch and having some trouble (probably lack of understanding on my part... still learning).

Basically on my homepage `('/')`, all I have is a DataSearch component that is used for providing autocomplete (much like google.com). When a suggestion is selected, it redirects (using RR4) to the /results route, which is a ReactiveList component. There is also a copy of the same DataSearch component in my global Header (Navbar.js) is conditionally rendered based on the route - displays on every route except for `('/')`.

Couple of things are going on:

1. When I make a query selection from the dropdown the home route `'/'`, and then redirected to the `'/results` route, the DataSearch text input is not blank - the previously selected query is there, it doesn't provide any **NEW** suggestions and the results shown are **NOT** based upon the selected query.
2. No actual search results based on the selected query are displayed from the ResultList component on the `/results` page - whether from `'/'` or `'/results` (suggestions are shown - not actual search results after query selection).
3. If I go to `/results` (from clicking on link in Navbar), the page automatically displays the ES index - even though no query is performed?

Not sure what is going on...

I took the relevant code (routes and components) from my app and made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o15k8o2o56) to demonstrate the behavior I'm describing.

Comment: Hey, checked your codesandbox. You can use `URLParams` prop for your search component on the `/results` route and set the URL query string when a search suggestion is selected by the user from the `/` route. You can get this with the `onValueSelected` prop of DataSearch. https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html#extending

Comment: @sidi - can you take another look at my codesandbox - made some changes and I believe I did what you said and I still have the same problem. The value of query is still undefined and the results are not based on the user submitted query

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @sidi for helping with this over at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/21jy31668r).

In my DataSearch component on my home route, it was all about my onValueSelected function, just had to add a bit of code:

```
<DataSearch
  ...
  onValueSelected={(value, cause, source) => {
  if (cause !== "SUGGESTION_SELECT") {
  // use this query
  console.log(
  "use this query - onValueSelected: ",
  this.query
  );
  this.setState({ redirect: true, value: value }); // value: value
  this.props.history.push(`/?q=${value}`); // added entire line
  } else {
  this.valueSelected = true;
  this.setState({ value }); // added enter line
  }
}}
```

In the first setState, `value: value` was added and also the `this.history.push(`/?q=${value}`);` too. Finally I was also missing the second `this.setState({ value });` in else clause.

In the if statement on both the '/' and '/results/ routes:

```
if (redirect) {
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/results",
            search: `?q=${value}`
          }}
        />
      );
    }
```

I was missing the `<Redirect>` in the `return ()`.

Sometimes, you just need another set of eyes on the code when you've worked on it for a few days.

HTH anyone else with ReactiveSearch! Great UI library for Elasticsearch.